# How to transfer file from Server to Android Mobile using Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

How to transfer file from Server to Android Mobile using Socket maintaining its format. It could be any file such as pdf, html, png, txt etc. I want to push this file from Server to Android Mobile but on the Mobile side while saving file I want to know the format of the file which came from the Server. So how it could be done?

```
private class ClientRxThread extends Thread {
        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;

        ClientRxThread(String address, int port) {
            dstAddress = address;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;

            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                String name = "test";
                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        name);

                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                byte[] bytes;
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    bytes = (byte[])ois.readObject();
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    fos.write(bytes);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if(fos!=null){
                        fos.close();
                    }

                }

                socket.close();

                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Finished",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }});

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                final String eMsg = "Something wrong: " + e.getMessage();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                eMsg,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }});

            } finally {
                if(socket != null){
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the client Side
I want to know how to get the file format of the file sent from Server

```
String name = "test";
                File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        name);
```

Want to know how to find file format of the file sent from SERVER. File from the Server could be html, png or txt FILE

Server Side relevant code

```
public class FileTxThread extends Thread {
        Socket socket;

        FileTxThread(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            File file = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "test.png");

            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bis;
            try {
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                bis.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject(bytes);
                oos.flush();

                socket.close();

                final String sentMsg = "File sent to: " + socket.getInetAddress();
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                sentMsg,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }


File file = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "test.png");
```

The test.png could have png, html, txt extension. So is there any way to send extension?

Comment: I don't know much about Sockets thats why I am asking.

Comment: I had already asked Google thats why I came here

Comment: If u can't help and if u don't know, then why did u comment and down vote my question.

Comment: Your question doesn't mean a specific issue, SO won't code for you. You have to show us some efforts done by you. Also I am not the one downvoted you **yet**. (I am helping you to ask the right question)

Comment: Yay..There you are.. You had post some codes. now tell us what is the error you got?

Comment: Did you tried `File.getName()`?

Comment: No, but does one get file extension from this?

Comment: I think you have to sent the filename from server too

Comment: i want to know the extension of that particular file before saving it so I could save the file with proper extension.

Comment: Ya, I understand . For that you have to sent the **filename and the file** itself from the server.

Comment: I am sending the file from the server. But the file could be of any extension such as test.html, test.png , test.txt. So How to get the file name with extension using Socket? How to do that?

Comment: Post the server side code. only relevant part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server side send the filename too.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "test.png");

ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(file.getName().getBytes());
oos.flush();

//then send the file
```

In Client side receive that name first and then read the file as second object

```
byte[] fileNameBytes = (byte[])ois.readObject();
String name = new String(fileNameBytes);

//read the second object as file
```

Comment: I am trying now and get to u back in 5 mins.

Comment: I have one doubt. On the client side how would I come to know whether I am sending file name or the actual file?

Comment: You define your own protocol in such a way that you send/receive the file name first. Followed by the file contents.

Comment: how to define protocol?

Comment: It is already defined by what i said: send the file name first.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you , [check this GitHub page](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sending-and-Receiving-Data-with-Sockets)